Are any of the new orexin antagonists in the ISS medicine cabinets?
This answer to What psychological issues do astronauts experience during spaceflight, caused by spaceflight? includes a block quote (from a (now broken link to an "ISS user's guide") which says:

The various procedures in this guide infer that the ISS has a small pharmacy aboard in its drug cabinet, containing several options each for analgesic pain relievers, antihistamines, decongestants, antiemetics, anti-diarrheals, sleep aids, etc up to the "hard stuff" like cortizone and albuterol steroids, opioid painkillers including hydrocodone and possibly morphine...

From what I have read here and elsewhere, a common challenge for at least some astronauts on long duration missions is routinely getting the amount of sleep each day that they feel they need. Challenges may include adapting to weightless sleeping mechanics and ubiquitous noise.
Until recently, most medical "sleep aids" did not really induce an actual sleep state proper, but may aid in relaxing to fall asleep. However recently a class of drugs known as orexin antagonists seem to come closer to the idea of a "sleeping pill" in that they

...improve sleep parameters including latency to persistent sleep (LPS), wake after sleep onset (WASO), sleep efficiency (SE), total sleep time (TST), and sleep quality (SQ).

This answer to How can astronauts on ISS deal with dental emergency? links to an ISS "medical checklist" but it's circa 2001. It mentions several hypnotics (Ambien (Zolpidem), Restoril (Temazepam), Radedorm (Nitrazepam)) and good old Benadryl. What medicines were onboard the Apollo flights? would not apply, nor would Why is there a pregnancy test kit on the ISS?
So while I'm not sure if it's answerable, I'd like to ask:
Question: Are any of the new orexin antagonists in the ISS medicine cabinets?
Note that there would probably be separate medicine cabinets for each side of the ISS.

I fixed the broken link in the dental question. I wasn't sure how to edit this question though. orexin isn't mentioned in the ISS Medical Checklist that I referenced there, but it's from 2001. Thanks for pointing out the broken link.

@OrganicMarble Oh that's excellent, thank you! I've made an update here - the reference is just part of my "due diligence" or "evidence of research"

+1 and Following, because I really like the questions that give you a glimpse into daily life in "unusual situations" like onboard a warship or the ISS.
